# How to check administrator of google apps domain?

Tags: java, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-authentication

I am using google oauth in my application, and I need to find out if that user is the admin of that domain. How do I do that?

Comment: Ninja (cool name btw), such topics are considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. Perhaps Quora may be a better place if you are looking for advice on how to proceed.

Comment: @dubes this question is legit as long as OP is asking how to programmability determine admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Admin SDK Directory API's [users.list()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) call while specifying a `query` parameter of `isAdmin=true` to pull a list of all super admin users in the Google Apps domain.

**Update:** with the new [roleAssignments.list()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/roleAssignments/list) call you can determine admin rights for super and delegated admins which offers a greater level of detail about which users have which admin privileges.